# warning: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, arduino

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <AFMotor.h>
Servo myservo1, myservo2, myservo3, myservo4;
AF_DCMotor motor1(1);
AF_DCMotor motor2(2);

int bluetoothTx = 10;
int bluetoothRx = 11;
char valor;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup()
{
  myservo1.attach(3);
  myservo2.attach(5);
  myservo3.attach(6);
  myservo4.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
  motor1.setSpeed(250);
  motor1.setSpeed(250);
}

void loop()
{
  if (bluetooth.available() >= 2 )
  {
    unsigned int servopos = bluetooth.read();
    unsigned int servopos1 = bluetooth.read();
    unsigned int realservo = (servopos1 * 256) + servopos;
    Serial.println(realservo);

    if (realservo >= 1000 && realservo < 1180) {
      int servo1 = realservo;
      servo1 = map(servo1, 1000, 1180, 0, 180);
      myservo1.write(servo1);
      Serial.println("Servo 1 ON");
      delay(10);
    }
    if (realservo >= 2000 && realservo < 2180) {
      int servo2 = realservo;
      servo2 = map(servo2, 2000, 2180, 0, 180);
      myservo2.write(servo2);
      Serial.println("Servo 2 ON");
      delay(10);
    }
    if (realservo >= 3000 && realservo < 3180) {
      int servo3 = realservo;
      servo3 = map(servo3, 3000, 3180, 0, 180);
      myservo3.write(servo3);
      Serial.println("Servo 3 ON");
      delay(10);
    }
    if (realservo >= 4000 && realservo < 4180) {
      int servo4 = realservo;
      servo4 = map(servo4, 4000, 4180, 0, 180);
      myservo4.write(servo4);
      Serial.println("Servo 4 ON");
      delay(10);
    }
    valor = Serial.read();
    if (valor == "W")
    {
      motor1.run(FORWARD);
      motor2.run(FORWARD);
    }
    if (valor == "A")
    {
      motor2.run(FORWARD);
    }
    if (valor == "D")
    {
      motor1.run(FORWARD);
    }
    if (valor == "S")
    {
      motor1.run(BACKWARD);
      motor2.run(BACKWARD);
    }

  }
}
```

Las instrucciones en las que me muestra el *warning* son:

```
...
char valor;
...
if (valor == "W")
...
if (valor == "A")
...
if (valor == "D")
...
if (valor == "S")
...
```

Comment: ¿ Es necesario quedarse ciego escudriñando las 83 líneas de código que has puesto para descubrir tu problema ? ¿ O hay que intentar compilarlo ? ¿ Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y añadir el código exacto que te genera el error ? Un saludo.

Comment: Buenas, ¿cómo puedo mirar en que líneas me salta el error?

Comment: Normalmente, el compilador lo indica cerca o en la misma línea en la que te muestra el mensaje; algo del tipo `file XXX, line YYY: warning: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]`. Pues `line YYY` es lo que estás buscando.

Comment: 63:16 , 68:16, 72:16, 76:16 Por lo que he estado mirando, es la parte inferior del código pero no sé como puedo arreglarlo.

Comment: Lo siento, soy nuevo en esto -.-

Comment: Bueno, a ver si para la siguiente sale mejor. Hoy no estoy precisamente *de buen humor*, siento haber sonado tan *borde*. Un saludo :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el código que has puesto al final te estás respondiendo al problema:

```
char valor;

// ...

if (valor == "W")
//  -----    ---
//  char     const char*
```

Estás intentando comparar dos tipos que no se pueden comparar directamente. Lo que debes hacer es usar `char`:

```
if (valor == 'W')
```

La diferencia es sutil, pero ahí está. Si no fuese por estos detalles programar en C++ sería muy aburrido.

Por otro lado, si bien es cierto que con las cadenas de texto no se puede, los `char` son más flexibles... has tenido suerte y puedes reemplazar todo ese atracón de `if` por un `switch-case`:

```
switch (valor)
{
  case 'W':
    // ...
    break;

  case 'A':
    // ...
    break;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!